# Can I replace the Shutdown button in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, shutdown

Can I change the Shutdown button to another one, like "Switch User"?

I would like the default accessible action / button to be switch user, and shutdown should still be available via the same menu Switch User is available today.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right click the shutdown button, select properties, and the resulting window (Start Menu and Taskbar Properties) lets you change it (to either Switch user, Log off, Lock, Restart, or Sleep).

and voila!

[image]

Comment: Sweet - I didn't imagine it would be this simple! :)

Answer (score 0):

http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/

That allows you to customize the start menu with some of the settings that were available in XP

Comment: Isn't that a bit overkill?

Comment: Depends on what you really want to do.  It's a light-weight app, either way.