# Windows 7 shutdown with countdown

Tags: windows-7

You have seen the way how Mac OS X shutdown would prompt user with countdown message before its will shutdown automatically, this will prevent user from accidentally end the session.

Is there a way to change the Windows 7 "Shut down" default behaviour to include countdown timer in case I forget to save my works on time?

Comment: You mean change the default behavior of the shutdown button?

Comment: yup, change the default behaviour to contain countdown timer. argh, sorry for being long winded in my post when I'm a software developer.

Comment: Not really possible, i dont think.

Comment: Oh, it's a usability issue for MS to fix then.

Comment: They have never had that feature in the 22 years I have been using Microsoft OS'es...I would not count on it any time soon.

Comment: I'm with KCotreau on this one.  How many people accidently hit the shutdown button anyways?  On our systems it defaults to sleep.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/178550/can-i-replace-the-shutdown-button-in-windows-7), and change to default to hibernate. Not really what you want, but it will do the same thing (stop you from shutting it down accidentally).

Comment: By the way, I was not copying you. I was in the process of making the screenshots and we basically were thinking the same thing. I was having trouble with the bottom one since every time I tried to use the screenshot program I use, it would close that menu I wanted to capture. I eventually went with print screen and pasted into paint, and cut what I wanted to a new file. I was just slow not doing it my usual way.

Comment: Its fine, I was the one that upvoted you. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no countdown feature, but you can avoid the accidental shutdown like this:

You can change the default by Right-clicking the taskbar and going to Properties>Start Menu>Power button action and changing it to "Hibernate".

[image]

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, and not sure its a good idea, but could you replace shutdown.exe with a program that called shutdown.exe -t 30? Forgetting about the side effects of course.

Comment: If you could somehow incorporate the command shutdown -t 30 into an executable, not batch file, and name it the same, it very well might work. You bring up and interesting point though, he could create a batch file and put in somewhere convenient to shut down, but then he could just as easily hit that. As a side note, I always create a file reboot.bat with the command "shutdown -r -f -t 00" for systems that I access remotely so they do not get hung up waiting for a click on "End Task" if one should happen to inhibit a reboot.

Comment: Its a bad idea as it would also (assuming that all it does is run shutdown.exe with preset arguments) override all the other functions of shutdown.exe. Should I post the source code/exe for such a program?

Comment: That is up to you and how well you have tested it to know that you may not be causing problems.

Comment: Too buggy to risk I think.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7, Run Command, type

`Shutdown -s -t 3600`

And the PC will schedule a full shutdown in 1 hour.

You will also get a reminder 10 minutes (approx) before shutdown. You can abort shutdown using `Shutdown -a`

This link has the full range of possibilities http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/shutdown.mspx?mfr=true