# Shutdown Timer with Password Protection

Tags: windows-xp, timer

I need an shutdown timer application that can run on Windows XP. I would like for it to require a password to cancel the timer.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Possibly: "I need a shutdown timer application that can run on Windows XP, but it has to have password protection so that nobody can cancel the timer without the password?"

Answer (score 4):

Use the built-in shutdown timer in windows, [`shutdown.exe`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491003.aspx). It lets you specify how long to display a warning for, and what the warning text should be. Cancelling the shutdown requires administrative privileges or granting the user permission via group policy to manage timed shutdowns.

To initiate a shutdown, use the following command from the command prompt. You can also create a desktop shortcut to it:

```
shutdown -t nn -s -c "Notice to show to user"
```

`nn` is the number of seconds to show the warning before shutting down. `-s` tells it to do a shutdown; you can use `-r` instead to do a reboot.

To cancel the command, open a command prompt from an administrator account, and type

```
shutdown -a
```

This will stop any timed shutdown in progress. To create a shortcut that will let any user do this if they have the administrator account's password, use:

```
runas -user:administrator shutdown -a
```

This will open a command prompt asking for the administrator account's password, and will then stop the shutdown.

If you need more control than these options offer, you may need to look for a third party program. These options however will work for any Windows computer and are built-in. You can also run the timed shutdown from a [scheduled task](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569) if you want the shutdown to occur at a certain time every day.

Comment: Brilliant. I was going to post the same thing.

Comment: +1: Additionally, if you get and use MS' [PsShutdown](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541) in place of Shutdown (works almost exactly the same) you can specify longer time-out intervals, as well as set it to shut down at a specific time of the day.

Answer (score 1):

As [this](https://superuser.com/questions/317190/windows-7-shutdown-with-countdown/317192#317192) question did not have a good answer (unless you are going to do some coding) I am inclined to say neither does yours.

In addition, what is to stop someone from just killing the process? Nothing a process can really do to prevent it.